# Self-made Wpf Controls Windows 10 Resolution issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I used a WPF control in my application for licensing. The control element seems ok on my monitor with resolution 1920x1200. But if I start the application on my 4K monitor, the control element is distorted. The display of my hosting program is ok.

[image]

Does anyone know any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of WPF are you targeting? And what version of .net Framework?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.0

Comment: You're most likely out of luck. The majority of WPF high-dpi improvements came after .Net 4.5

Comment: As the previous commenter mentioned the dpi scaling feature is missing on this control.